# How to insert logged in username inside database using sessions

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

My code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connection.php';
$uname = $_SESSION['user'];
echo $uname;

$sql = "INSERT INTO user_activity_log (username)
VALUES ('$uname')";

if (sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "record could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
  
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I am getting output, but it is not getting inserted and I am getting this as error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22001 [SQLSTATE] => 22001 [1] => 8152
> [code] => 8152 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]String or binary data would be truncated. [message]
> => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000
> [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 3621 [code] => 3621 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been
> terminated. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. ) )

Comment: Output is talking about truncation. What is the $uname value in your example ? And what is the size or your user_activity_log column in DB ?

Comment: it consist of username priyap only 6 letters and its size is 30 varchar

Comment: Try `trim` the $uname first before executing the insert query

Comment: And always use parameterized statements to prevent possible SQL-injection issues. Function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries.

Comment: Just to bang the drum more about how **dangerous** your code is: [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: what is your sql server version? if its earlier than sql 2019 try using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`.